# Grepping across multiple directories

Tags: grep, recursive

I want to run this:

```
grep -r zlib *.cpp
```

But this fails unless there is a .cpp file in the current directory (in which case only it is searched):

```
 grep: *.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Now:

```
grep -r zlib *
```

Does search through the whole hierarchy but I want to limit the search to (eg) .cpp files.

Looked through man and a lot of recipe sites but cannot find an answer to what I assume is a simple query - so apologies in advance.

Comment: `grep: illegal option -- r`, better use `find` tigether with `grep` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing do with `grep`, but with your current shell. The shell expands `*.cpp` to all the cpp file names in your current directory before running the `grep` command. Since it can't find any filenames, the glob `*.cpp` is left unexpanded by the shell. The `grep` command tries to see this is a file, but cribs that it is not a real file.

You have couple of options, use `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -exec grep -r zlib {} +
```

or if you are using a `bash` shell, set a nullglob option to stop returning un-expanded glob as a valid result. The `(..)` is to make the extended shell option temporary and not make it persistent in the shell. The reason to have the `--include=*.cpp` option is, with the option set, if the glob expansion fails `*.cpp` becomes empty and your command becomes `grep -r zlib` which means search in entire sub-directory below.

```
( shopt -s nullglob; grep -r --include=*.cpp zlib . ; )
```

Another variant that doesn't include the `--include` option of `grep` but using the `globstar` that allows recursive glob expansion in sub-directories

```
( shopt -s nullglob globstar; grep -rH zlib **/*.cpp  ; )
```

Remember the `--include=` and `-H` are GNU grep options and not POSIX compatiable

Answer (score 0):

zsh shell users would be quick to point out that they have a built in globbing syntax that allows for this naturally by using a double asterisk:

```
grep -r zlib **/*.cpp
```

You can just run 'zsh' as a one time thing if you want by just running 'zsh', you don't have to switch to it permanently.